# add-adgroupmember in winfoms

Tags: windows, winforms, powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script for creating domain users. I am stuck on add-adgroupmember.
Error messgae:"Add-ADGroupMember: Cannot convert 'Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported."  All you need to do is change the "UserPrincipalName" and the code will work on any domain.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$textboxName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxPassword = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxDescription = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$addbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$droplist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$labelname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelPassword = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelDescription = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelOU = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$checklist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$Password = New-Object System.Security.SecureString

$droplist.Location = '150,200'
$droplist.width = 240
$droplist.Height = 20
$oulist = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' 
$droplist.Items.AddRange($oulist)
$labelOU.Text = 'OU'
$labelOU.Location = '150,180'

$checklist.Location = '185,80'
$checklist.Size = '200,100'
$checklist.CheckOnClick = $true
Get-ADGroup -Filter * |Select-Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\Windows\Temp\adgroup.txt
$grouplist = Get-Content C:\Windows\Temp\adgroup.txt
$checklist.Items.AddRange($grouplist)

$addbutton.Text = 'Add'
$addbutton.Location = '196,23'
$addbutton.Add_Click({
    $Password = $textboxPassword.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    If($textboxName.Text){New-ADUser $textboxName.Text -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $Password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Description $textboxDescription.text -UserPrincipalName ($textboxName.Text+'@matt.lab') -Path $droplist.Text | Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $checklist.CheckedItems -Members $textboxName.Text -Confirm} 
})
....
```

Comment: Not at work to run the script, but pretty sure you need to loop through the list of groups to add your single user to each one. You can't pipe the user to Add-ADGroupMember with an array of simple string names which is what your checkllist is. Obliquely this is what the error is referring to.
Don;t try to do it all at once, create the user, then add it to the list of groups.
I;d advise you also use the -Server parameter to ensure all requersts go to the same DC.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235): The `Identity` parameter *Specifies an Active Directory group object by providing one of the following values.*  Which means it expects a single item not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, **dont use** `LoadWithPartialName`, but instead do `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`, because the [LoadWithPartialName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadwithpartialname?view=net-5.0#remarks) method is declared obsolete.

As already commented by others, the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet cannot take an array of group names as input, so you should do this by looping over the checked items in the CheckedListBox:

```
$addbutton.Add_Click({
    # easiest is to use Splatting for cmdlet that take a lot of parameters
    $newUser = @{
        Name                  = $textboxName.Text.Trim()
        Enabled               = $true
        AccountPassword       = $textboxPassword.Text.Trim() | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
        Description           = $textboxDescription.Text.Trim()
        UserPrincipalName     = '{0}@matt.lab' -f $textboxName.Text.Trim()
        Path                  = $droplist.Text
        # add more properties here if needed
    }

    try {
        $user = New-ADUser @newUser -ErrorAction Stop
        foreach ($group in $checklist.CheckedItems) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.ToString() -Members $user -Confirm
        }
    }
    catch {
        # show the error in the GUI somewhere or use a popup alert box like
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
        $message = $_.Exception.Message
        [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox($message, "OKOnly,SystemModal,Critical", "Error creating user")
    }
})
```

However, relying on user input always needs extra care and you should create some helper function to test if all required boxes are filled in properly before allowing to click the button or call on such a tester function before trying to create a new user and adding this to several groups.